# HTTParty JSON parsing

Tags: ruby, httparty

Hi I am trying to parse an `xml` url using `httparty`:

```
auth = {:username => "xxxx", :password => "yyyyyy"}
@blah = HTTParty.get("https://example.com/", 
                     :basic_auth => auth)
```

when am using the url in browser am getting like this

```
<event>
  <eventCode>....</eventCode>
  <name>....</eventCode>
</event>
```

but when am parsing the `httparty` response using
`JSON.parse(@blah.body[9...-2])`
I am getting
`{"eventCode"=>"code", "name"=>"eventname"}`

I need a response like this:
`{"event" => {"eventCode"=>"code"}}`

So that I can get value by

```
@blah["event"]["eventCode"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
require "json"
Hash.from_xml( xml ).to_json
```

Comment: It requires ActiveSupport, more specifically Hash extensions: `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'`

Comment: Ouch. Im just on phone, couldnt verify mY answer. Should i delete it ?

Comment: You definitely can get the same result by using `nokogiri`.

Comment: Ok , ill to on with mY Travel :p

Comment: Yes, I don't understand this.

Comment: No in rb file am trying to use httparty..., If i can use nokogiri mean anybody can tell how to use authentication in nokogiri please.

Comment: why am getting parsed response like this 
#<HTTParty::Response:0x3208d68 parsed_response="callback({\"eventCode\":\" ?

Comment: @sakthivel, what do you mean? That's a `HTTParty::Response` object. If you need response body, try `@blah.body`.

Answer (score 0):

If `@blah.body` is

```
<event>
  <eventCode>....</eventCode>
  <name>....</eventCode>
</event>
```

then you should just be able to do

```
@blah["event"]["eventCode"]
```

without parsing. `httparty` allows to do that.